# Getting a sub-class out of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am learning how to code around a project that I am trying to build. So heres a snippet of some JavaScript that I'm executing with Google Maps API:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {


    console.log("Formatted Address: "+ results[i].formatted_address + "\n" + 
        "Geometry: "+ results[i].geometry.location + "\n" + 
        "Types: "+ results[i].types + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[0].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[0].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[1].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[1].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[2].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[2].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[3].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[3].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[4].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[4].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[5].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[5].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[6].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[6].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[7].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[7].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[8].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[8].long_name + "\n" +
        results[i].address_components[9].types + ": " + results[i].address_components[9].long_name
    );

    formattedAddress = results[i].formatted_address;
    coordinates = results[i].geometry.location;
    types = results[i].types;
    // component = results[i].address_components[0].types;

    no = i+1;

    output += "<li>";
    output += "<p><i>"+ no +"</i></p>"
    output += "<p><b>"+ formattedAddress +"</b></p>";
    output += "<p>"+ coordinates +"</p>";
    output += "<p>"+ types +"</p>";
    output += "</li>";

    //console.log("results for "+ [i] + " :" + output);
    $("#list-locations").html(output);
}
```

I am trying to read & output the address components (.types & .long_name) which can vary length depending on the search term.  Some search terms will only return 1 types & long_name field, whereas other search terms could return 7 or 8.

I am ultimately looking to add it to my output variable.

Here is an example JSON Return:

```
{
  "types":["locality","political"],
  "formatted_address":"Winnetka, IL, USA",
  "address_components":[{
    "long_name":"Winnetka",
    "short_name":"Winnetka",
    "types":["locality","political"]
  },{
    "long_name":"Illinois",
    "short_name":"IL",
    "types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
  },{
    "long_name":"United States",
    "short_name":"US",
    "types":["country","political"]
  }],
  "geometry":{
    "location":[ -87.7417070, 42.1083080],
    "location_type":"APPROXIMATE"
  },
  "place_id": "ChIJW8Va5TnED4gRY91Ng47qy3Q"
}
```

In this example `address_components[2].long_name` would return "United States", whereas `address_components[3].long_name` would return `undefined`.

How can I add a counter, so that ...`address_components[j].long_nam`e is the length of the no. of fields in the specific search term (`j` being that number)?

Comment: Uhm, `var j = address_components.length` ?

Comment: `var j = address_components.length -1`

Comment: Seems to work.  Just getting my head around a way of placing all of the content into an output.  Rather tired, so I'll post my revised code as an answer tomorrow.  Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: @localghost what is the purpose of the -1 at the end?

Comment: The index of an array is zero based. So when you use the array.length you need to substract 1 to get a valid index. 
Example: `var a = [11,22,33];` The length is 3 but when you access `a[3]` you get `undefined`. But `a[3-1]` returns `33`.

Comment: @localghost Gotcha.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I solved the problem by doing the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

    formattedAddress = results[i].formatted_address;
    coordinates = results[i].geometry.location;
    types = results[i].types;

    no = i+1;

    output += "<li>";
    output += "<H1><i>"+ no +"</i></H1>"
    output += "<p><b>"+ formattedAddress +"</b></p>";
    output += "<p>"+ coordinates +"</p>";
    output += "<p>"+ types +"</p>";
    for (j = 0; j < results[i].address_components.length; j++) {
        comp = results[i].address_components[j].types;
        compCont = results[i].address_components[j].long_name;
        output += "<p>"+ comp +": " + compCont +"</p>";
    }
    output += "</li>";

    $("#list-locations").html(output);
}
```

As per @localghost comments, if I went less than or equal to I would need the -1